# cov-analyze with list of checkers

Tags: coverity

What's the best way to enable a list of checkers in Coverity Analize.  I've got a list of checkers but don't want to enable them all.

To enable all you can either leave blank or --all

```
cov-analyze --dir cov
```

or

```
cov-analyze --dir cov --all
```

I want to have a list like the following but many more . . .

```
cov-analyze --dir cov -en STRING_NULL -en NULL_RETURNS
```

Can you have a small text file to read?  Or do you just have to list them all out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're mainly asking how to avoid listing all of the checkers on the command line, you could use a [response file](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs/page/commands/topics/cov-analyze.html#refsection_b3j_lf2_4qb__response_file):

> **@@<response_file>**
>
> Specify a response file that contains a list of additional command line arguments, such as a list of files for analysis. Each line in the file is treated as one argument, regardless of spaces, quotes, etc.

With that, your analysis command line would look like:

```
cov-analyze --disable-default @@enable-checkers.txt <other options like --dir>
```

where `enable-checkers.txt` contains:

```
--enable
STRING_NULL
--enable
NULL_RETURNS
...
```

with the `...` consisting of additional pairs of lines consisting of `--enable` followed by a checker name.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Coverity documentation](https://sig-product-docs.synopsys.com/bundle/coverity-docs/page/commands/topics/cov-analyze.html#refsection_k22_4f2_4qb):

> `--disable-default` Disables default checkers. This option is useful if you want to disable all default checkers, including Sigma checkers,
> and then enable only a few with the --enable option.
>
> For a list of checkers that are disabled through this option, see the
> --enable option documentation for the cov-analyze command.
>
> `--enable <checker_name>`
> `-en <checker>` Enables a checker that is not otherwise enabled by default. The checker name is case insensitive. This option will enable
> a checker for all languages supported by the checker.

Comment: So, how I have it above is the way to do it?  Except just add the --disable-default?